# Gradle Input password from keyboard: System.console() return null

Tags: gradle, input, keyboard

Gradle: input password from keyboard:

```
task Foo {
    doLast {
        def passwd = System.console().readPassword("password:")
    }
}
```

System.console() return null.
How to input password from keyboard?

Comment: This is likely because you are running it in a way that an interactive console is unavailable. Could you expand on your use case? (Is this supposed to happen in a particular task or when configuring a task, are you running it from an IDE or a terminal?)

Comment: updated. run in a Task.

Answer (score 0):

'Password's First letter suppose to be in Capital.

```
// read password
def passwd = System.console().readPassword("Password: ");

// prints
System.out.println("Password is: "+pwd);enter code here
```